# Help with Gaussian elimination

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

What is the memory, that is used with the cpu of the computer, to solving Gaussian elimination methods? I don't know how to answer this question.

$\quad$,Thank you  in advance

Comment: Since we can overwrite the coefficients, we only need the memory for the coefficients of the given equation system, so the space we need is $O(n^2)$ , if the number of equations and unknowns is $n$.

Comment: thank you peter for your help

Comment: Technically, the space for the input data is not counted. So an implementation with LU decomposition requires $O(1)$ space.